# How to change color wheel size

Tags: color-management

I am trying to make a new material but I have trouble picking colors due to the color wheel size. Is there a way to increase the size of the color wheel?

Comment: if you zoom in the Shader Editor you will be able to have a big color wheel

Comment: if you are talking about the Material panel maybe try Ctrl + middle mouse button to increase the size?

Comment: .... or `Numpad +` if you have no middle mouse button (laptop)

Comment: Thanks Guys. I was trying to resize the little popup panel that shows the color wheel when clicking on the Base Color for example. And I couldn't resize it. I now realize that one has to resize the entire panel first and then click on the Base Color. Now the wheel popup is large. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to resize the little popup panel that shows the color wheel when clicking on the Base Color for example. And I couldn't resize it. I now realize that one has to resize the entire panel first and then click on the Base Color. Now the wheel popup is large.